How to remove all occurrences of an underscore before a pattern?
In R, how do we remove all occurrences of an underscore before a pattern?
For example:
x <- c("a_b_test_1", "a_b_c_test_2")

I would like to achieve:
x
[1] "ab_test_1"  "abc_test_2"

by removing all underscores before "_test"
Tidyverse solution preferred but base R is also fine.

library(stringr)

str_replace_all(x, "(.*)(?=_test)", \(x) str_remove_all(x, fixed("_")))
# [1] "ab_test_1"  "abc_test_2"


Maybe you can try
> u <- gsub("_", "", sub("_test.*", "", x))

> v <- sub(".*(_test.*)", "\\1", x)

> paste0(u, v)
[1] "ab_test_1"  "abc_test_2"


First consume _test_ and everything after it replacing all that with itself or if it is already consumed remove _ in what is left.
gsub("(_test_.*)|_", "\\1", x)
## [1] "ab_test_1"  "abc_test_2"

Note
Input used
x <- c("a_b_test_1", "a_b_c_test_2")

